# Unable to declare function as variable outside main function in golang

Tags: go

Is working example

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var newFunc func(int, int) int
    newFunc = func(i int, j int) int {
        return (i * j)
    }

    fmt.Println(newFunc(10, 20))

}
```

But if I taken out the function declaration part, out of main function (as shown below), it fails to compile.. Is mandatory to declare it inside main() function ?

```
package main

import "fmt"

var newFunc func(int, int) int
newFunc = func(i int, j int) int {
    return (i * j)
}

func main() {


    fmt.Println(newFunc(10, 20))

}
```

Compile Err details as follows:

```
.\functionanonymous1.go:6:1: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
.\functionanonymous1.go:6:15: missing function body
.\functionanonymous1.go:6:33: method has multiple receivers
.\functionanonymous1.go:7:2: syntax error: unexpected return, expecting )
.\functionanonymous1.go:8:1: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
```

Comment: Someone voted down for close ,**Yes I agree, for experienced users this seems to be an unwanted foolish question.** but I have a humble question if I delete this question , then user who answered this question **will loose reputation points ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Go, while declaring variables outside functions, every declaration must begin with a keyword (ie. `var`). It might be kept in that way so that the parsing is less complicated.

So outside of functions, you can't assign a value to some pre-declared variable (i.e. `v = 1` ) and also can't use short variable declarations (i.e. `v := 1`). You may have noticed that from the error logs, `syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body`.

```golang
package main

var a int

a = 1 // illegal
b := 1 // illegal

var c = 1 // legal

func main() {}
```

**Updated code:**

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

var newFunc = func(i int, j int) int {
    return (i * j)
}

func main() {

    fmt.Println(newFunc(10, 20))

}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0XMyZcnTrDr)

Comment: "A go program with short variable declarations outside a function doesn’t compile" - OP's code doesn't use a short variable declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, golang doesn't allow that. A variable that declares outside function must contain `var`.

So you can try:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var newFunc func(int, int) int = func(i int, j int) int {
     return (i * j)
}

func main() {
     fmt.Println(newFunc(10, 20))
}
```